# Get screen size to choose matching header picture

Tags: javascript, arrays, sniffer

Hej,
I had a JavaScript solution for checking the screen size and choosing a matching picture. But I lost this unfortunately.

**My Problem**: I want to choose a header picture (CSS responsive not possible) regarding to the screen size. Visitor with 1920x1080 will see a picture matching to this size. For usual sizes I will build special header pictures.

When Visitor has JavaScript disabled he should see a standard picture.

Mobile device has it´s own header.

Can anyone please help out…Thanks :)

Best Regards
Madeleine

Comment: can you provide code for this question which you tried to fix your problem by yourself? without code it's really hard to find out what you want to achieve.

Comment: http://javascriptisnotjava.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of ways to check the screen size:

If you are using **jQuery** you can use the screen object in the following way:

```
screen.width;
```

You can also get the size of the window or the document using:

```
$(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
$(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

Here is a cross browser solution with pure **JavaScript**:

```
var width = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;
```

Regarding **responsive images without using Media Querys**, **Flexbox** is a great Solution:

```css
body { margin: 0; background: #333; }
header { 
  padding: .5vw;
  font-size: 0;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}
header div { 
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto; 
  width: 200px; 
  margin: .5vw; 
}
header div img { 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
}
```

```html
<header>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-1.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-2.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-3.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-4.jpg" alt></div>
<div><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/jeremiah-wilson-5.jpg" alt></div>
</header>
```

Resize this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/frontendzone/pen/XRNbLQ) to see a **Flexbox Responsive Header**

If you header image is set as a `background image` you can set:

```
background-size: contain

background-size: cover
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :)
I can’t use responsive pictures for my header, flexbox is nice but I really can’t use it. Sorry. The only way for me is to check screen size and use header for each screen size.
Yes, I´m using jQuery and have to use the JavaScript solution, but don’t know where to start.

Comment: And how to check the sizes to use the right header images?! Is this a good way to start below?

<pre> <code>if $(window).width() > ???) { add header1920 } else { add standardpicture }</pre> </code>

Answer (score 1):

If you are Using jQuery, you can check the Screen size (when the document structure is ready) and display acoordingly your wanted image:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($(window).width() < 960) {
     $('selector').css({'background-image':'url(images/small-
  image.jpg)'});

  }
  else {
     $('selector').css({'background-image':'url(images/big-image.jpg)'});
  }

});
```

Comment: **Could I use this too?!**

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($(window).width() = 800) {
     $('selector').css({'background-image':'url(images/image800.jpg)'});
  }
  else if ($(window).width() = 1024){
     $('selector').css({'background-image':'url(images/image1024.jpg)'});
  }
  else if ($(window).width() = 1280){
     $('selector').css({'background-image':'url(images/image1280.jpg)'});
  }
  else {
     $('selector').css({'background-image':'url(images/standardimage.jpg)'});
  }
});
</script>`

Thank you !!

Comment: yes sure! just don't forget to replace the jQuery Selector $('selector') with the name of your class or ID that displays the background-img.
If you need more help:
frontendzone@gmail.com

Comment: Many thanks for your awesome support. But unfortunately it does not work?